# Magento 2.0 Static Content Deploy PHP Fatal Error

Tags: magento-2.0, php-7, static-content

**INSTALLED MAGENTO 2.0 IN FOLDER on UBUNTU 16.10**
SAME CSS ISSUE AGAIN...

cd /var/www/html/store
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower(
) in /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:56

sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring

/var/www/html/store# sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
****** php7.0-mbstring is already the newest version (7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~yakkety+1). ******
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

ALREADY INSTALLED?

sudo service apache2 restart

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower(
) in /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:56

***************************************AGAIN

cd /etc/php/7.0/apache2
nano php.ini

EDITED
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
TO
extension=php_mbstring.dll

SAVE
EXIT

sudo service apache2 restart

cd /var/www/html/store
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower() in /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:56
*********************************** AGAIN

Multibyte String
mb_strtolower — Make a string lowercase

cd /etc/php/7.1/apache2
nano php.ini

EDITED
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
TO
extension=php_mbstring.dll

SAVE
EXIT

sudo service apache2 restart
cd /var/www/html/store
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\Event\mb_strtolower(
) in /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:56

---

EDITED BOTH PHP.INI
Both 7.0 and 7.1 Filesize upload 256M AND Uncommented ;extension=php_mbstring.dll
Thats the only thing I've changed.

****** HELP **************************** ///

Comment: try `php bin/magento setup:static-content: deploy -vv` now you'll able to see the error trace

Answer (score 0):

First check the PHP Path in command:

```
$ whereis php
```

Following output will display:

```
 php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/share/php7.0 opcache /usr/share/php /usr/share/php7.0-xml /usr/share/php7.0-json /usr/share/php7.0-readline /usr/share/php7.0-mysql /usr/share/php7.0-common /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

After that try this command:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause for this**

Disabled mb_strtolower extension for OS PHP handler that is defined by mbstring PHP module.

Also it sounds like when running CLI php, it's using the /usr/local/bin one that does not have mbstring installed.

```
/usr/local/bin/php -m
```

and check whether it was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart php and php-fpm (if you are using) after you enabled "php_mbstring" ? Also, please check if mbstring is enabled by printing `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 0):

According to your current Magento version. Install following this system requirements.

[- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)

And also Install depending libraries(PHP Extensions). this will resolve your issue.

Thanks